# MongoDB $lookup with conditional foreignField

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/OxMnsCFZpmQ

My MongoDB version: 4.2.

I have a collection `car_parts` and `customers`.
As the name suggests `car_parts` has car parts, where some of them can have a field `sub_parts` which is a list of `car_parts._id`s this part consists of.

Every customer that bought something at us is stored in `customers`. The `parts` field for a customer contains a list of parts the customer bought together on a certain date.

I would like to have an aggregate query in MongoDB that returns a mapping of which car parts were bought (`bought_parts`) from which `customers`. However, if the `car_parts` has the field `sub_parts`, the customer should show up for the subparts only.

So the query in the playground gives almost the correct result already, except for the `sub_parts` topic.

Example for customer_3:

```
{
      "_id": "customer_3",
      "parts": [
        {
          "bought_parts": [
            3
          ],
          date: "15.07.2020"
        }
      ]
   }
```

Since `bought_parts` has `car_parts._id` = 3:

```
{
      "_id": 3,
      "name": "steering wheel",
      "sub_parts": [
        1, // other car_parts._id s
        2
      ]
 }
```

The result should show customer_3 as a customer of car parts 1 and 2.
I'm not sure how to accomplish this, but I assume a "temporary" replacement of the id 3 in `bought_parts` with the actual ids [1,2] might solve it.

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "customers": [
      "customer_1",
      "customer_2",
      "customer_3"  // <- since customer_3 bought car part 3 which has 1 in sub_parts
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "customers": [
     "customer_3"  // <- since customer_3 bought car part 3 which has 2 in sub_parts
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "customers": [
      "customer_1", // <- since car_parts.id = 3 has [1, 2] in sub_parts, show customers of ids [1, 2]
      "customer_2",
      "customer_3"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "customers": [
      "customer_1",
      "customer_2"
    ]
  }
]
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You can do another lookup...The question is: can there be more than two levels?

Comment: It would only be one level, the id will not be nested any deeper.

Comment: According to your explanation the requested results should be: [
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "customers": [
      "customer_1",
      "customer_2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "customers": [
      "customer_3"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "customers": [
      "customer_1",
      "customer_2",
      "customer_3"
    ]
  }
]

Comment: Or do you want part 3 to include customer 3 as well? It should not include customers: 1 and 2...

Comment: yes, part 3 should include customer_1, _2 and _3, since the customer_3 initially bought part 3, but, indirectly by buying part 3 also bought parts 1 and 2 and for those the customers are customer_1 and customer_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: One way to do it is:

```
db.car_parts.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      topLevel: {$concatArrays: [{$ifNull: ["$sub_parts", []]}, ["$_id"]]},
      sub_parts: 1
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$topLevel"},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$topLevel",
      parts: {$push: "$_id"},
      sub_parts: {$first: "$sub_parts"}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      parts: {$concatArrays: [{"$ifNull": ["$sub_parts", []]}, "$parts"]}
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "customers",
      localField: "parts",
      foreignField: "parts.scanned_parts",
      as: "customers"
    }
  },
  {$project: {customers: "$customers._id"}}
])
```

As you can see working on [this playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2MydZxZHNj2).

Since you said there is only one level of sub-parts, I used another idea: creating a top level before the `$lookup`. Since you want customers that used part 3 for example, to be registered under parts 1,2 which are sub-parts of 3, the idea is to group them. This connection is a bit clumsy after the `$lookup`, but if we use the data that we have on the `car_parts` collection before the `$lookup`, we actually knows already that parts 1,2 are subpart of 3. Creating a `topLevel` temporary field, allows to group, in advance, all the parts and sub-parts that if a customer used on of them, he should be registered under this top level part. This makes things much more elegant...

Comment: Unfortunately not, since documents in `customers` do not have to have the field `parts`, this somehow screws the aggregation results up somehow. I currently try to resolve it somehow, but without success so far. Thank you anyway for the initial proposal!

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fZFugFec9y3) the problem?

Comment: yes, exactly! ...

Comment: The result for `car_parts._id = 3` doesn't seem right to me, before it was correct: "_id": 3,
    "customers": [
      "customer_3",
      "customer_1",
      "customer_2"
    ]

Comment: Updated the answer. It looks good to me now :)